# CSS alignment and width with percent

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

Hi guys I want to aligning two divs ( one right with 30 % width and one left with 70 %). I searching a long time but nothing is working . I hope someone can help me.

I am using primefaces 3.5 and jsf 2.1 and i use e primefaces Theme from jQuery.

Here is my template:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/META-INF/templates/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="verticalAlignTop,verticalAlignTop">
            <p:panel id="panelTemplContSplitLeft" styleClass="left"
                style="border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
                       -moz-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
                       -webkit-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
                       border: 2px solid #080808;
                       background: #fcfcfc; width: 350px; ">
                <ui:insert name="contentLeft">
                    <h:outputLabel value="This is default Content Left" />
                </ui:insert>
            </p:panel>

            <p:panel id="panelTemplContSplitRight" styleClass="right"
                style="border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
                       -moz-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
                       -webkit-border-radius: 13px 13px 13px 13px;
                       border: 2px solid #080808;
                       background: #fcfcfc; width:800px;">
                <ui:insert name="contentRight">
                    <h:outputLabel value="This is default Content Right" />
                </ui:insert>
            </p:panel>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

This is a part from my theme.css

```
.verticalAlignTop { vertical-align: top; }

.right {
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 1em;

    right: 0px;
}

.left {
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: are your div displayed as inline-block, table-cell or floatting , or none of these. if just block, they will stack.

Comment: as block if i remove the width component from the panelGrid.
Here you can see a picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p7pcn67bt0304lo/pic.JPG

Comment: okay, so your width + padding + margin should not exceed 100%, here you have 30 + 70 + margin wich is more than 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** Calculate the below marked widths and they will be > 100%, so your divs wont align in one line

```
.right {
    width: 70%; /*this is a width */
    margin-left: auto;/*this is a width */
    margin-right: 1em;/*this is a width */

    right: 0px;/* why do you have this when you dont have "position" attribute?*/
}

.left {
    width: 30%;/*this is a width */
    margin-left: 1em;/*this is a width */
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sn7Bn/1/)

**Solution :**

```
.right {
    width: 60%; /* either reduce this  */
    margin-left: auto;/*or remove these */
    margin-right: 1em;/*or remove these */
    display:inline-block; /*added*/
}

.left {
    width: 25%;/* either reduce this  */
    margin-left: 1em;/*or remove these */
    margin-right: auto;/*or remove these */
    display:inline-block; /*added*/
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sn7Bn/)

Comment: sry but nothing is changes

Comment: I realy hate CSS why nothing changes ;(
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrq59t4zwz6ayfw/picUpdated.JPG

Comment: @bvb1909 : the 2 `div`s showing side by side are the one needed to be arranged?

Comment: @bvb1909 : come on chat using below link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46634/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-bvb1909)